# Comparison of two dataframes with different Lengths:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, data-science

I need help writing a function that compares two dataframes and returns the cells that are different.

The column names will be the same across the two dataframes, but the length might not be.

I have example code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('11','12','13'),
        ('21','22','23'),
        ('31','32','33')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,
                 columns = ('col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3' ))


data2 = [('11','12','13'),
        ('21','22','23')]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,
                 columns = ('col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3' ))


df_mask = df.compare(df2, keep_shape=True).notnull().astype('int')

df_compare = df.compare(df2, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)

def apply_color(x):

    colors = {1: 'lightblue', 0: 'white'}

    return df_mask.applymap(lambda val: 'background-color: {}'.format(colors.get(val,'')))

df_compare.style.apply(apply_color, axis=None)
```

This will throw an error:
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Dataframe objects.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do something like this, use `pd.merge()` with an indicator to determine which rows are in both dataframes or not:

```
check = pd.merge(df, df2, on=['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'], how='left', indicator='Exist')
check_both = check[check['Exist'] == 'both']
check_df_only = check[check['Exist'] == 'left_only']
check_df2_only = check[check['Exist'] == 'right_only']
```

check_df_only is only the data in df that is unique to itself, check_df2_only is only the data in df2 that is unique to itself, and check_both is the data that is in both dataframes.

Comment: what if I want to return the cells that are not matching in both?

Comment: @MFaragal you could do something like ```check_not_matching = check[(check['Exist'] == 'right_only') | (check['Exist'] == 'left_only')]```. This will return a dataframe that contains only values that are 'left_only' or 'right_only'. Or you could do ```check_both = check[check['Exist'] != 'both']```. This returns the same thing.